# static method vs new class

Tags: java, class, static-methods

In my program I have a class "Team" that holds data for each object of team. 
Now I am trying to create an ArrayList of "Team" objects, but I was wondering if it is better practice to create a new class to do so, or if I should just perform that task in a static method of "Team".

I have searched for the answer, but only found comparisons of static vs non-static questions/answers. Where I am more interested in when I should make a new class vs using a static method.

Thank you for your help

Edit: Primarily what I am asking here is whether the methods "dataExtract" and "hasTeam" (as shown in the code below) should be in their own class, or kept as static methods where they are.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Team {
String country;
String skaterNames;
int points;

    public Team(String cntr, String sktrNames, int point){
        country = cntr;
        skaterNames = sktrNames;
        points = point;
    }

    public Team(){}

    public static ArrayList<Team> dataExtract(FileInput file){
        ArrayList<Team> al = new ArrayList<Team>();
        while (file.hasMoreData()){
            String tempLine = file.readLine();
            if (hasTeam(al, tempLine.substring(0, 3)) == -1){
                al.add(new Team(tempLine.substring(0, 3), tempLine.substring(3, 30).trim(), Integer.parseInt(tempLine.substring(37))));
            }
            else {
                al.get(hasTeam(al, tempLine.substring(0, 3))).skaterNames += (", "+ tempLine.substring(3, 30).trim()); 
                al.get(hasTeam(al, tempLine.substring(0, 3))).points += Integer.parseInt(tempLine.substring(37));
            }
        }
        return al;
    }
    public static int hasTeam(ArrayList<Team> al, String team){
        for (int i =0; i<al.size(); i++){
            if (((Team) al.get(i)).country.equalsIgnoreCase(team))
            return i;

        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why you create a new class is for reusability.

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. When you don't want to create a object to access the method , make the method as static. Basically it all depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: may we see your code?

Comment: @KRUKUSA I figured as much, but my professor likes to create new methods very liberally. e.g. making a new class just to print the data of an array of objects in a particular format, even though it could only be used for that particular type of object.

So in this case I should just use a static method, right?

Comment: Alright this question has been flagged as [on hold] for being to broad. I apologize that I was not more precise in my question. I have added to the question (marked as "Edit:" in the question now,) so it can be answered in just a sentence or two. 

This is my first question posted to this site, and would appreciate any feedback as to how to avoid this situation again. 

It is a little confusing because I do not believe my question is very broad, and I am not provided with any indication as to what is making it seem too broad. 
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case a static method is probably ok. The advantage of a non-static would be either future edits (i.e. if the class grows anything that changes the non-constant fields or references them would become an error source) and generally neatness. Keeping your methods inside variables allows you a living changing variable that can be very useful. In your particular case, though, that isn't the purpose of the class.

Static makes the method callable without creating an object of the class. Sometimes this can be good, for example all the Math class methods (Math.round, Math.ceil, etc.). Static should only be used when the method only uses it's own parameters. Even then sometimes it's better to leave it non-static. It's kept cleaner and you always know what you are actually editing.

If static methods use variables that are initialized in the constructor there could be a problem. If an object of this class isn't initialized, then the constructors aren't initialized. This could cause bad side effects and program errors.

Generally only use static if the class is merely a housing for a method that is completely standalone.

Comment: Well the static method "dataExtract" creates the objects that it is referencing, so I'm not really sure when there would be an instance where the variable would not be initialized. I may just be misunderstanding what you are trying to say, other than that I think I understand what you are saying.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Balthazarion Yeah, you're right changing the answer to fit a more general sense.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is just what I was looking for. I think I will end up creating a separate class for these static methods, as it seems that would better align with the spirit of OOP. As well as keep myself from forming bad programming habits.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'd better mention that I'm in High School, and have only known Java since the beginning of the school year. So I'm hardly an authority. But glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You should create non-static classes for re-usability, the ability to make subclasses, etc. If you have something like a "team" (whatever that may refer to), it's generally considered better practice to make a Team class and create several instances of it. Given that you're creating multiple Team objects, using static methods/field would just be too confusing and unorganized.